# DialogFlow: Respond appropriately to name that ends in "s" or when user inputs a possessive name without an apostrophe

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot

How can Dialogflow distinguish appropriately between the following questions for example:

- Show me Frances' account
- Show me Frances's account
- Show me Frances account
- Show me Francess account

Looking for the response to be correct such as:

- Here is Frances' account

or

- Here is Frances's account

I'm using the @sys.person entity but often its not recognizing the variations properly. I've tried training about 10 examples and still having troubles.

Comment: Also having issues with names that dont end in "s" but where the possessive "s" does not have an apostrophe. For example: "Show me Peters account"

Comment: Welcome to SO; comments are not the right place to add info or extend questions - please edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Dialogflow to improve at recognizing 's or s behind a persons name you can use [composite entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-developer#developer_composite). These composite entities allow you to look for a value in a certain pattern, which in your case could be [person]'s, [person]', [person]s and [person]

If you use the @sys.Person entity in this new composite entity, it should work for any name that is recognized by the @sys.Person entity. So you don't have to write an example for each persons name.